# Setting code highlighting in Knitr RMD document

Tags: r, knitr

I am trying to set the Knitr highlighting in a .Rmd doc by putting this at the top of my file:

````
```
<<theme, cache=FALSE, echo=FALSE>>=
library(knitr)
thm = knit_theme$get("olive")
knit_theme$set(thm)
@
```
````

Why isnt my syntax being highlighted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't read the documentation `?knitr::knit_theme`: [it does not work for R Markdown.](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/5c245a90c3ce2ef12093219e9f2ca871c7e4cd0b/man/knit_theme.Rd#L22-L27)